# how to build docker-image and use it with k8s in github actions?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, github-actions

I have a monorepo of 2 packages:

1. produces a docker-image
2. has tests that deploy (locally) to k8s the image from package-1

to make sure that k8s will talk to the local docker deamon and take the image from there, in my local machine, I run:

1. eval $(minikube docker-env --shell sh)
2. locally build the docker-image in package-1 (no docker-push)
3. run the tests in package-2

---

In github-actions, I tried to do run the same commands, but the first step doesn't work: (https://github.com/stavalfi/k8test/pull/6/checks?check_run_id=785330120)

```
Run eval $(minikube docker-env --shell sh)
/home/runner/work/_temp/932fe76c-855f-4ed6-9fa3-dcd5cea6df7e.sh: line 1: README.md: command not found
##[error]Process completed with exit code 127.
```

I have no-idea what does this error means and why "README.md" appears in the error.

### Question:

Is there any way to make it work? even an alternative way to make sure that in github-actions, k8s will find the docker-image that I build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I created a working solution for this problem.
I'm not sure why I got that error but here is a working solution:

github actions configuraiton file:

```
name: Node.js CI

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: secrethub/actions/env-export@v0.1.0
        env:
          SECRETHUB_CREDENTIAL: ${{ secrets.SECRETHUB_CREDENTIAL }}
          DOCKER_USERNAME: secrethub://stavalfi/dockerhub/username
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: secrethub://stavalfi/dockerhub/access-token
      - name: install k8s
        uses: engineerd/setup-kind@v0.4.0
      - run: minikube start
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn build
      - run: eval $(minikube docker-env --shell sh) && yarn workspace simple-service build:docker # build the docker image and let k8s use it locally
      - run: eval $(minikube docker-env --shell sh) && yarn workspace k8test-monitoring build:docker # build the docker image and let k8s use it locally
      - run: DEBUG=k8test:* yarn test # create k8s deployments from the docker-images from the last 2 steps
```